# Prove that $f(x) = 0$ for some $x$ under the assumption that there exists a continuous function $g$ such that $f + g$ is non decreasing.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

Let $f(0) > 0$, $f(1) < 0$. Prove that $f(x) = 0$ for some $x$ under the
assumption that there exists a continuous function $g$ such that $f + g$ is
non decreasing.

A hint for this problem says the following: bisect the interval $[0,1]$ choosing the right interval of the mid point if there's $x$ in the right interval for which $f(y)\ge 0$. Otherwise choose the left interval. As such you will form $[a_n, b_n]=I_n$ such that $a_n, b_n \rightarrow c$. It turns out $c$ is our desired point. The hint goes further and states that, 'notice that for all $n$, there's $y_n \in [a_n, c]$ such that $f(y_n)\ge 0$'. Here's where I am confused. (I tried very hard to prove it but I couldn't) I do not want a proof of this statement (if it exists). I am just looking for a sanity check. Could the $[a_n, c]$ actually be $[a_n,b_n]$? Was it just a typo?

Comment: Could I get a suggestion on how to improve this question since it's not getting a lot of attention?

Comment: It was not a typo, the statement is correct.

Comment: @MBW I give up. Could you explain to me why there's $y_n \in [a_n,c]$ such that $f(y_n)\ge0$?

Comment: Don't feel bad.  It took me a while also,

Comment: An easier proof would start: Let $c = \inf\{d : \text{$f(y) < 0$ for $y \in [d,1]$}\}$.

Comment: Note that both conditions:
1. $f+g$ is monotonic increasing,
2. $g$ is continuous,
are crucial.
Without either one of them, the proposition is false.
You may need to clarify your working steps and show exactly where you have invoked them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n_m$ be the (possibly finite) subsequence so that the $[a_{n_m},b_{n_m}]$ are the left intervals. See that $f(y) < 0$ for all $y \in [b_{n_m}, b_{n_{m-1}}]$.  In this way, it must be the case that $f(y) < 0$ for all $y \in \bigcup_m [b_{n_m}, b_{n_{m-1}}]$.  And $(c,1] \subseteq \bigcup_m [b_{n_m}, b_{n_{m-1}}]$.

Comment: I found your response very enlightening, and thank you for your encouraging words!

Answer (score 1):

Let $g:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such
that $h:=f+g$ is monotonic increasing on $[0,1]$. Observe that if
$x\in(0,1)$, right-hand limit $f(x+)=\lim_{t\rightarrow x+}f(t)=\lim_{t\rightarrow x+}h(t)-g(x)$
exists. Similarly, left hand limit $f(x-)=\lim_{t\rightarrow x-}f(t)$
exists.

Let $A=\{x\in[0,1]\mid f(y)>0 \mbox{ for all } y\in[0,x]\}.$ Note
that $A\neq\emptyset$ (because $0\in A$) and bounded above by $1$,
so $\xi=\sup A$ exists. We go to show that $\xi\notin A$ by contradition.
Suppose the contrary that $\xi\in A$, then $f(\xi)>0$. Note that
$\xi<1$. For each $x\in(\xi,1]$, $x\notin A\Rightarrow\exists y\in(\xi,x]$
such that $f(y)\leq0$. From which we can choose a sequence $(y_{n})$
in $(\xi,1]$ such that $y_{1}>y_{2}>\ldots>\xi$ , $y_{n}\rightarrow\xi$,
and $f(y_{n})\leq0$. Letting $n\rightarrow\infty$, we have $f(\xi+)\leq0$.
Observe that $0\leq h(\xi+)-h(\xi)=f(\xi+)-f(\xi)<0,$ which is a
contradiction.

$\xi\notin A$ implies that there exists a sequence $(x_{n})$ in
$A$ such that $x_{1}<x_{2}<\ldots<\xi$ and $x_{n}\rightarrow\xi$.
Therefore $f(\xi-)=\lim_{n}f(x_{n})\geq0$. Now, $0\leq h(\xi)-h(\xi-)=f(\xi)-f(\xi-)$,
so $0\leq f(\xi-)\leq f(\xi)$. Finally, we go to prove that $f(\xi)=0$.
Prove by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that $f(\xi)>0$. Let
$t\in[0,\xi)$ be arbitrary, then $t$ is not an upper bound of $A$.
Therefore, there exists $x\in A$ and $x>t$. In particular $f(t)>0$
by the very definition of $A$ (because $x\in A$ and $t\in[0,x]$).
Hence, we prove that $f(t)>0$ for each $t\in[0,\xi)$. Together with
the fact that $f(\xi)>0$, we have $\xi\in A$, which is a contradiction.